# Is there a way to flip a UV without flipping the normals?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a UV unwrapped object that I want one part of to show its texture flipped horizontally, but I can't seem to find a way to do this other than flipping the normals, but I'd prefer not to do that as it seems to mess up other things. Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Select all in UV Edit window and type <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd> and enter

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that you could use negative numbers for scaling. Does that work on meshes too?

Comment: Yes - scaling to -1 is common for flipping a selection, it also works in other areas - graph editor, dopesheet, node editor, movie clip, sequencer...

Comment: That's a neat solution! Thanks @Patdog